# Need (AutoFill + Multi Select) Drop down control in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, multi-select, autofill

One of my client has asked for both "Multi Select and Auto Fill" feature in single control.
Look at this image:

[image: Auto Fill Ajax + Multi Select]
I want something like above.
Control should have both Ajax based auto fill and Checkbox based multiselect feature.

Please tell me where can I get such type of control?

Comment: did you ever find a control for your desired UX?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Chosen plugin](http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-chosen.php) should do the trick.  Slightly different formatting, but same effect you are after.

Comment: Does it support Ajax auto fill?

Comment: Try this other version - ajaxChosen - http://blog.meltingice.net/programming/bootstrapping-chosen-ajax-autocomplete/